# Incrementing ticket numbers each time I print

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing, vba

I have an excel sheet to print a set of 4 tickets per page which we use for stock takes.

I found code that prints one number per page. Being a Visual Basic for Applications novice, I was unable to change the code to suit my preferences.

Rather than creating a huge document with 1000 pages for 4000 tickets each with a unique ticket number (starting from 1) I would like to find a macro or function which will print a page with 4 tickets (1,2,3,4) then another page with (5,6,7,8) and so on.

If someone could explain simply how I could achieve this I would be very very grateful :)

Comment: You'd need to maintain the current number scheme as well as the script. My suggestion is to build a script that updates the static cells where these numbers reside, then updates a "hidden" cell with the last number it used, as a place holder for the next time.  You'd also need this script to save the document after every print, or else you'll lose all your changes. The alternative is to have your worksheet read/write this info from/to a secondary file.

Comment: Do you have any examples of the kind of code I would need to use for any of this? I have never used visual basic to edit macros before and I'm rather unskilled on the programming front! :(

Comment: [Intro to Excel VBA](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introduction-to-custom-macros-in-excel-HA001118958.aspx) Here is [how to build functions](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/writingfunctionsinvba.aspx) [How to Update a Cell Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245095/excel-2010-vba-change-a-cell-value-in-a-table-during-a-for-loop) Here is [how to save the file](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/67564-visual-basic-applications-code-save-workbook-no-prompt.html) [How to read/write to a File](http://www.homeandlearn.org/open_a_text_file_in_vba.html)